# Logwatch not showing FTP (Proftpd) success or failed logins, only shows uploades/downloads

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, configuration, logwatch

Server: CentOS 5.2, Proftpd 1.3.3d, Logwatch 7.3-8.el5.noarch (updated with yum).

I've just setup Logwatch and got the email output, it does show some FTP info for example it shows uploaded and downloaded files. There are lots of failed FTP attempts in /var/log/secure but they are not shown in the Logwatch email.

It would be nice if Logwatch could list the IP's with the amount of attempts, is that possible? Would be nice to show successful logins too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with pure-ftpd, perhaps you could add the following line or similar to your /etc/syslog.conf:

```
# Save pure-ftpd messages to transfer.log
ftp.*                                                   /var/log/transfer.log
```

Only thing you have to do now is process those lines in your transfer.log using logwatch.

Comment: Will logwatch automatically pickup the transfer.log file though?